# Flask route to download .xml files leading to 404 Not Found

Tags: python, angularjs, nginx, flask, debian

I have a `flask` (0.10.1) app running on a `Debian Jessie VPS` and powered by `nginx` (1.6.2). The app is working fine but I have a problem on a specific `route` I added recently.

The `route` is intended for downloading `.xml` files.

It is dynamic to tell the directory and the file name:

```
@app.route('/backups/<dir_key>/<filename>')
```

And it registers a function based on the `flask` `send_from_directory` function:

```
def backups(dir_key,filename):
    directory = os.path.join(app.config['BACKUPXML_FOLDER'], dir_key)
    return send_from_directory(directory, filename, as_attachment=True)
```

The route is generated thanks to the `flask` `url_for` function, and returned to the frontend:

```
return jsonify({
    'backupFileUrl': url_for('backups', dir_key=dir_key, filename = filename, _external=True)
})
```

where it is stored in an `AngularJS` variable:

```
$scope.backupFileUrl = response.backupFileUrl;
```

And finally included in a `<a>` tag for download :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"
   ng-show="sessionDownload"
   ng-href="{{ backupFileUrl }}" target="_blank">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Télécharger </a>
```

But when I click on the button, I get the following error :

[image]

What is weird to is that :

1. The download is properly triggered when the app is powered by a small `Python` server on a local `Windows` machine.
2. I have a `route` intended for downloads of `.xlsx` files which is actually working, and both on a local `Windows` machine and on the `Jessie VPS`.

Someone see how I can define the `route` to make it work ?

Here is the api architecture if needed :

**api/app.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')

from flask_script import Server, Manager
from kosapp import app, db

manager = Manager(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    manager.run()
```

**api/config.py**

```
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
import tempfile

basedir = dirname(abspath(__file__))
BASEDIR = dirname(abspath(__file__))

DEBUG = True

REPORTS_FOLDER = '/tmp/reports'
# on local machine 
# REPORTS_FOLDER = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'reports') 

BACKUPXML_FOLDER = '/tmp/backups'
# on local machine
# BACKUPXML_FOLDER = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'backups')
```

**api/kosapp/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
app.config.from_object('config')

from kosapp import views
```

**api/kosapp/views.py**

```
import os

from flask import send_file, jsonify, request, render_template, send_from_directory

from kosapp import app

@app.route('/reports/<dir_key>/<filename>')
def reports(dir_key, filename):
    directory = os.path.join(app.config['REPORTS_FOLDER'], dir_key)
    return send_from_directory(directory, filename)

@app.route('/backups/<dir_key>/<filename>')
def backups(dir_key,filename):
    directory = os.path.join(app.config['BACKUPXML_FOLDER'], dir_key)
    return send_from_directory(directory, filename, as_attachment=True)
```

As a note, the route `'/reports/<dir_key>/<filename>'` is intended for downloading `.xlsx` file and works fine.

Comment: Why not let Nginx serve the files for you?

Comment: Do you mean by directly pointing to the file in the `<a>` tag ?

Comment: You are using Flask to serve files from a particular folder. Nginx will do that much better. You can set up an alias or location to match the prefixes you need to match.

Comment: Your remark made me dive a little bit into the Nginx configuration (which I didn't do), and I think the problem is the definition of the `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file. I should add `backups` to the line `location ~ ^/(api|auth|me|reports)`. I'll give it a go, and give update about what happened. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to reload the app on the server? That's usually the problem if i get different results on my development computer and the web server.

For instance, if you deployed with `gunicorn`, you would have to restart `gunicorn` so the server would know about the changes to your code.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I restarted the app.